# Relaxation of a (possibly infeasible) QP that is always feasible while remaining a QP

Tags: optimization

I am currently working on a problem that requires a solution to a standard QP
of the form $$ \min_{z \in \mathbb{R}^n} z^TQz + q^Tz \quad s.t. Az \leq b, \, Q \succ 0, $$
with $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ that that could potentially be infeasible ($Az \leq b$ is an empty set). I would like to solve a different QP that recovers the true solution if the original QP is feasible and any solution + the possibility to detect the infeasibility of the previous problem in case it is infeasible.

I'm considering something like 
$$ \min_{z \in \mathbb{R}^n, r \in \mathbb{R}^m} z^TQz + q^Tz + r^T R r\quad s.t. Az \leq b + r, \, R,Q \succ 0. $$
Through some appropriate choice of $R$, I'm hoping to recover $r = 0 $ if the original QP is feasible and $r \neq 0 \, (r > 0 ?)$ otherwise.

Does this in general make sense? Or can you think of a different solution? Can I atleast expect that $r$ will be "small" in case the of feasibility of the original problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "$Az \le b$ could be non-convex"?  Is $z \mapsto Az$ not a linear transformation?

Comment: You are right, $A z \leq b $ has to be convex. So I guess I am only considering the case where $ A z \leq b$ is empty!  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, it's called exact penalty functions (keyword for searches). Instead of quadratic, you typically use a linear penalty $\lambda r$ with $r\geq 0$. For sufficiently large $\lambda$, the solution satisfies the properties you desire.